# unable to update when 0(zero) value is stored for empty fields in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-update

I have a non mandatory phone textbox field and the datatype is int. If I leave the phone field blank and submit the  form, phone column is stored with 0(zero) in database. I am facing issue with update:
while updating when phone is '0' the respective row is not updated.
Do I need to set the default value of phone as null? if so please explain.

Here is my update query

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE client_final SET companyname = @companyname, url = @url, industry = @industry, contactperson1 = @contactperson1, contactperson2 = @contactperson2, designation = @designation, fax = @fax, phone = @phone, mobile = @mobile, emailid1 = @emailid1, emailid2 = @emailid2, baddress = @baddress, bcity = @bcity, bstate = @bstate, bzipcode = @bzipcode, bcountry = @bcountry, regaddress = @regaddress, regcity = @regcity, regstate = @regstate, regzipcode = @regzipcode, regcountry = @regcountry WHERE client_id = @client_id";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client_id", txtClientId.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyname", txtcompanyname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url", txturl.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@industry", drpindustry.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactperson1", txtcontactperson1.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactperson2", txtcontactperson2.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@designation", txtdesignation.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fax", txtfaxnumber.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", txtphone.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", txtmobile.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailid1", txtemailid1.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailid2", txtemailid2.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@baddress", txtbaddress.InnerText);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bcity", txtbcity.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bstate", txtbstate.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bzipcode", txtbzipcode.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bcountry", bddlCountries.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regaddress", txtraddress.InnerText);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regcity", txtrcity.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regstate", txtrstate.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regzipcode", txtrzipcode.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regcountry", rddlCountries.Text);
```

Comment: what error does it give when you update?

Comment: @Dheeraj Sharma Error is not displayed but when click on button all fields get blank.

Comment: it could be possible that there is some error in your code instead of query, because having 0 in any fields doesn't stop query from executing, please elaborate your problem.

Comment: I have added my update query and if it is a problem with query then i should not work in any condition.

Comment: you code is pretty fine, problem is somewhere else, you can use a try catch block and use a break point to grab the error.

Answer (score 1):

as your datatype for phone column is int, and default value for int is 0. please specify this column as nullable in database then everything should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @sampletable TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),phonenumber INT)

INSERT INTO @sampletable VALUES('') -- here is your insertion

SELECT * FROM @sampletable          -- as you said column is updated with 0 if sent blank

UPDATE @sampletable SET phonenumber = '' WHERE ID = 1 --if we update, this works fine

SELECT * FROM @sampletable          -- again it is updated with 0 because we passed blank

--Where is the problem??
```

Answer (score 0):

In any table column if you don't wants to mark as mandatory then you must have to set allow null, because if it consider default value **"0"** like in your scenario rather then **NULL** then it may create problem on later stage. Best approach is to set **Allow Null** for your scenario.

For Example You have other column say for **TypeId** and it's type is **INT**, so now if user not enter in this column it is better to set **NULL instead 0**. Because some time user use Enum object which has may be 0 value associated with any type.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work in your scenario

Replace update query like below,

```
UPDATE client_final 
SET companyname = @companyname, 
    url = @url, 
    industry = @industry, 
    contactperson1 = @contactperson1, 
    contactperson2 = @contactperson2, 
    designation = @designation, 
    fax = @fax, 
    phone = NullIf(@phone, ’0’), 
    mobile = @mobile, 
    emailid1 = @emailid1, 
    emailid2 = @emailid2, 
    baddress = @baddress, 
    bcity = @bcity, 
    bstate = @bstate, 
    bzipcode = @bzipcode, 
    bcountry = @bcountry, 
    regaddress = @regaddress, 
    regcity = @regcity, 
    regstate = @regstate, 
    regzipcode = @regzipcode, 
    regcountry = @regcountry 
WHERE 
    client_id = @client_id;
```

use [NullIf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql) Function to update Null value instead of 0